how to display the landing page using payload cms, for now only the template is visible i want to display the complete landing page
I have successfully generated the landing page template but i am not able to view it as a whole landing page. I want the landing page to be visible as a whole.
I have tried using the Next.js code and taken help from various youtube channels also but didn't receive any positive output.
how to display the landing page using payload cms, for now only the template is visible i want to display the complete landing page
